# Is it possible to display: none a list of queries without using an object or array?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to `display: none` a list of queries without using an object or array?

Here is a pseudocode with the list of queries I want to select and hide in a minimal way:

```
(function fbPurity () {
let hide = {
    document.querySelector("#mako");
    document.querySelector("#gaga");
    document.querySelector("._top");
    document.querySelector(".yo");
    document.querySelector(".col");
}

hide.style.display = "none";
})();
```

Hiding these in the following way works but can be repetitive and inefficient when you work with a list of about 20-30 queries (as you would have about 60 rows to hide these).

```
let annoyingColumn = document.querySelector(".col");    
annoyingColoumn.style.display = "none";
```

**Why I prefer not to use an object or array in this case:**

Objects and arrays necess me to use properties or keys, and to wrap both these and their values with quote marks. It seems to me that this will redundantly lengthen the code while I desire just a simple list.

**My question:**

What should I use for a simple list of querySelectors, all having `display: none` in one command (as in the pseudocode)?

Comment: Should have been `document.querySelectorAll('.col')`. You still have to loop over them though.

Comment: "Objects and arrays necess me to use properties or keys, and to wrap both these and their values with quote marks." this isn't true or a good reason not to use an array. Given the psuedo code you've shown you **should** use an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns NodeList that has `forEach` so:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#mako,#gaga,._top,.yo,.col").forEach(function(el) {
   el.style.display = "none";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
function hideCollection(selector){
  var a = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for(var i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    a[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  return a;
}
hideCollection('.col');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small function that takes a selector and hides the according element, then use a simple array of selectors and call `forEach` passing to it that function. Like this:

```
function hide(selector) {
    document.querySelector(selector).style.display = "none";
}

["#mako", "#gaga", "._top", ".yo", ".col"].forEach(hide);
```

Comment: That will only hide the first `.col`.

Comment: Looks like you need to read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)... and remember, this is not jQuery.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir `querySelector` returns first matched element. What if you have two `.col` elements?

Comment: @c-smile OP is already using `querySelector` on `.col` element. So apparently he wants to hide one!

Comment: Even if you changed `querySelector` to `querySelectorAll`, it still won't work, since a `NodeList` is returned. If the `.style` property is used directly on a `.querySelectorAll()` only the first Element that is found on the DOM will be styled.

Comment: @PHPglue I didn't change it and I'm not gonna change it! Plus I know JS 101 so no need to explain!

Comment: @PHPglue By the way you can not use `style` on a `NodeList`! You must be confusing it with the way jQuery works!

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this instead:

```
let hide = ["#mako", "#gaga", "._top", ".yo", ".col"];
$(hide.join(",")).hide();
```